# How to solve "java.lang.illegalargumentexception collector already registered that provides name"?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, health-monitoring, spring-micrometer

**[image: strong text]**

How to solve "java.lang.illegalargumentexception collector already registered that provides name" ?
Meter registry class is below :

```
    @Configuration
public class RegistryConfig {

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        return registry -> registry.config().commonTags("app.name", "appname");
    }


    @Bean
    public CountedAspect countedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new CountedAspect(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        return new TimedAspect(meterRegistry);
    }

}
```

i found a link in which it was suggested to make your metric static  :
https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/issues/279
Please help me what exactly need to be done ? where i need to make static?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry`, then don't forget to clear it between the runs/reloads:

```
CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.clear();
```

Comment: your answer is helpful, but if you could add some explanation on the why part, it would benefit us more.

Comment: clear it where?

Comment: in `afterEach` method